# How to ingest a csv from blob storage without knowing the schema?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I would like to ingest a csv file from blob storage to a new kusto table without calling out the csv schema before-hand.  The destination will be a new table so there is no need to map columns.  Whatever columns are in the CSV will be the columns of the new table. Something like this:

```
.set-or-replace testtable <|
externaldata(*)
[
  h@"https://test.blob.core.windows.net/cont/test1.csv?...SAS..."
]
with(format="csv")
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: You won't be able to do it from within ADX, but there are other ways to do it from outside ADX, such as Functions, ADF & ADB, just to name few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
.ingest into table T ('adl://contoso.azuredatalakestore.net/Path/To/File/file1.ext;impersonate')
  with (format='csv')
```

> The CSV mapping, which is optional and is the ordinal based – As the
> name suggests, this mapping is done when the source file is in the csv
> format and its schema does not match the schema of the database table.
> One advantage with this mapping is that if the table or even if the
> column within the table does not exist, it will be created

[Data Ingestion Preparation: Schema Mapping](https://azure-training.com/azure-data-science/data-ingestion-preparation-schema-mapping/)

Comment: The mapping needs to be defined ahead/as part of the ingestion, which leaves us with the original problem. P.S. I would strongly recommend working with the documentation and not with blogs, since they tend to stale very fast.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported.

You'll need to get the schema first, for example by using [infer_storage_schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/inferstorageschemaplugin).